# Nginx serve images from multiple static directories under one alias

Tags: windows, nginx

I am making transition from apache to nginx, and i can not get the alias to serve images. Reading nginx documentation, diving in google and what not have not yielded any acceptable results for me ;(

The images is located `C:/xampp/htdocs/content/XYZ/thumbn/image.jpg`

the `XYZ` part is dynamic and changes.

Nginx is set up to serve content from  `root C:/nginx/public_html/domain.dev/`

In the apache i had simply made `Alias /CDN "C:\xampp\htdocs\content"`

So that way when ever i request `www.domain.dev/CDN/XYZ/thumbn/image.jpg` i would get the image from the alias directory.

So im trying to replicate the same in nginx

```
location /CDN {
alias C:/xampp/htdocs/content;
autoindex on; # just there to see if it works.
}
```

Unfortunately when i access the image `www.domain.dev/CDN/XYZ/thumbn/image.jpg` i get 404. In the Nginx logs i see following record :

```
2017/07/04 16:43:32 [error] 10532#6488: *4 CreateFile() "C:/nginx/public_html/domain.dev/CDN/XYZ/thumbn/two.jpg" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.domain.dev, request: "GET /CDN/XYZ/thumbn/two.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.dev"
```

it is how ever listing the directory contents.

Now if i change the location block to this

```
    location ^~ /CDN/ {
        alias C:/xampp/htdocs/content/;
    }
```

I get the same error in log, only way i managed to get it working (but not in the way i need) was when i use this location block

```
    location ^~ /CDN/ {
        alias C:/xampp/htdocs/content/XYZ/thumbn/;
    }
```

Then it is showing the image, but the url for the image is different and not valid for my project.

Now the question: how do i serve only images from multiple static directories under same alias?
the images are located in following structure

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/content/one/thumbn/image.jpg
C:/xampp/htdocs/content/two/thumbn/cats.jpg
C:/xampp/htdocs/content/three/thumbn/dogs.jpg
C:/xampp/htdocs/content/another_random_direcotry/thumbn/random.jpg
```

And they should be accessed by URL as follows

```
www.domain.dev/CDN/one/thumbn/image.jpg
www.domain.dev/CDN/two/thumbn/cats.jpg
www.domain.dev/CDN/three/thumbn/dogs.jpg
www.domain.dev/CDN/another_random_direcotry/thumbn/random.jpg
```

Is this even possible with Nginx? so how do i achieve this? Is regex required in this occasion?

full config file [here](https://pastebin.com/0Qx79cTd)

Comment: forgot to mention im running win 10 (production site will be on windows 2012 r2) and nginx-1.13.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
location /CDN/ {
        alias C:/xampp/htdocs/content/;
}
```

Comment: hi this was the first solution i tried and this is not working im getting the same error 404 and logs show : 

`2017/07/05 08:36:19 [error] 9360#3756: *1 CreateFile() "C:/nginx/public_html/domain.dev/CDN/two-vod/thumbn/two.jpg" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.domain.dev, request: "GET /CDN/two-vod/thumbn/two.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.domain.dev"`

Comment: if i put index.html in the `C:/xampp/htdocs/content/two-vod/thumbn/` and then access the URL`http://www.domain.dev/CDN/two-vod/thumbn/` then i get the contents of the index.html file. Why is it not working for ,jpg? does other file require specials perrmissions to be acces with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by

```
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 7d;
    }
```

When i comment out this location directive i can access the images from alias directory.

This how ever removes expiration header for images and with this enabled i can not access the images.

Comment: Is this the wrong way to leverage image browser caching? Why is it only interfering with images under alias directory?